# because it saves the child in minuscule firebase, even though my properties are in upper case

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, setvalue

Because it keeps the child in minuscule firebase, even though my properties are in upper case

[image]

```
mActividadReferencia.child(Actividad.getActividadID()).setValue(Actividad, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

            if(databaseError != null)
            {
                exito=true;
            }
            else
            {
                exito=false;

            }
        }
    });
```

POJO

```
public class Actividad {

    private String ActividadID;
    private String CustomerID;
    private String Kunnr;
    private String Descripcion;
    private String CodUsuario;
    private Date FechaIniPlan;
    private Date FechaFinPlan;
    private Date FechaIniReal;
    private Date FechaFinReal;
    private Double LatitudPlan;
    private Double LongitudPlan;
    private Double LatitudReal;
    private Double LongitudReal;
    private Date FechaCrea;
    private String Observacion;
    private String Estado;
    private String MotivoNoActividad;

    public Actividad() {
    }
```

I would thank you very much for your help, and if there any to to infring your child in capitals without a map.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is happening because Firebase is looking in your model class after fields that are **`not`** starting with a capital letter. If it finds fields like yours, it will replace that field with the corresponding first non-capital letter field. You should take a look on [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) to know how can you correctly name your `classes` / `methods` / `fields` in Java. In your case, the correct way to model your class would be:

```
public class Actividad {
    private String actividadID;
    private String customerID;
    private String kunnr;
    private String descripcion;
    private String codUsuario;
    private Date fechaIniPlan;
    private Date fechaFinPlan;
    private Date fechaIniReal;
    private Date fechaFinReal;
    private Double latitudPlan;
    private Double longitudPlan;
    private Double latitudReal;
    private Double longitudReal;
    private Date fechaCrea;
    private String observacion;
    private String estado;
    private String motivoNoActividad;

    public Actividad() {}

    //public setters and getters
}
```

Comment: Change the properties of the class to minuscule and follow the same